# Call function referring to object from input python

Tags: python, input, dynamic, call

So I have a class with a print function.

**Goal:** I want to be able to write "c1" in the input field to make
a call equivalent to c1.prnt().

Current error says "*AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prnt'*"

I guess the input is passed as a string but should be passed as a pointer to c1 in this case,
how do I do this?

```
    class claim:
        def __init__(self,text,support_list):
            authors = ["Author A","Author B"]
           #base_properties.__init__(self,authors)
            self.text = text
            self.support_list = support_list

        def prnt(self):
            n = len(self.support_list)-1
            print(f"\nThe claim -{self.text}- is backed by {c1.support_list[n].name} and {n} more.") 

   c1 = claim("Tax is mean",[s1,s2])

   input("What claim do you want to print?").prnt()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the objects in a dictionary so you can map names to the objects.

```
claims = {}
claims['c1'] = claim("Tax is mean",[s1,s2])

claims[input("What claim do you want to print?")].prnt()
```